# Is there any significance to what the Apprentice did in the season finale?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In the finale for season 4 of *Once Upon a Time*, we see the Apprentice use the hat on

> a dying Rumplestiltskin. The hat removes the darkness from his heart, but it's **white, and not red.**

Is there any significance to this(the bolded part), or was it an editing mistake?

Comment: thus far, they've been pretty consistent in the use of colors for magic, but I dunno that we know the details behind this one...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: that was my thought. They've been pretty consistent with things. But this ONE time?

Comment: to me that implies it means something, but you're right it could have just been a mistake in post producton

Answer (score 5):

Previously, on *Once Upon a Time*... No seriously, in the episode before hand, S4E23 (Part 1, mind you):

> "Do we really need color? Do we need to settle for what came before? Don't you want to really see the world? It's a complicated place. And people are complex creatures. **Their interior lives are painted with many different hues and shades.** And the Zenith Marseilles color TV..." –The Author

To me it implies purity of emotion. There's no love; no hate. If one were to be so cruel as to pull the heart from a new born child, I'd expect it to be as such.

In the next episode, in the scene to which you refer, the Apprentice says that he "was the dark one for centuries. His return to the man he used to be will not be easy."

Consumed by the darkness for so long, there's nothing else left inside. The reset button on his soul was pressed. He is now a blank slate.

Now, I could be wrong in my interpretations, but it *is* highly significant one way or another. But we won't know for sure *why*, "until we discern if we can help him" and know *how* we'll have to go about doing that.

Comment: I agree, the whiteness seemed very deliberate. And it seemed to signify the removal of his "darkness". Which is similar to Emma being often portrayed as "white"/pure, and Lily being dark.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is answered in the latest episode S5E03 in which

> Emma kidnaps Gold and wakes him up from his coma and tells him that she can turn him into a hero because now he is a blank slate. The blank slate meaning that he is not a villain nor a hero yet.

Hence the white color

Comment: OMG, the season started?! I've been working so much I didn't even notice. :(

Comment: only three episodes released. You can catch up during the weekend. After you see the third episode you will understand your question :D

This season also answered another question I had but didn't post
Why Belle's true loves kiss didn't remove the Dark One's magic in storybrooke. But it was shown why

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Well did you see the episodes?

Comment: Sadly, no. Too much work to do. But I will shortly.